# Appending and overwriting when joining dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have the following three dataframes:

```
prim <- data.frame("t"=2007:2012,
                   "a"=1:6,
                   "b"=7:12)

secnd <- data.frame("t"=2012:2013,
                    "a"=c(5, 7))

third <- data.frame("t"=2012:2013,
                    "b"=c(11, 13))
```

I want to join `secnd` and `third` to `prim` in two steps. In the first step I join `prim` and `secnd`, where any existing elements in `prim` are overwritten by those in `secnd`, so we end up with:

```
     t  a  b
1 2007  1  7
2 2008  2  8
3 2009  3  9
4 2010  4 10
5 2011  5 11
6 2012  5 12
7 2013  7 NA
```

After this I want to join with `third`, where again existing elements are overwritten by those in `third`:

```
     t  a  b
1 2007  1  7
2 2008  2  8
3 2009  3  9
4 2010  4 10
5 2011  5 11
6 2012  5 11
7 2013  7 13
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `dplyr` or base R?

Comment: Based on your question, the output of the first step should be different from the one presented: 2012 is not overwritten although it is present in `second`?

Comment: @AbdallahAtef Thanks, you are right - I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `dplyr` you can do:

```
require(dplyr)

prim %>% full_join(secnd, by = 't') %>%
  full_join(third, by = 't') %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(as.integer(a.y),a.x),
         b = coalesce(as.integer(b.y),b.x)) %>%
  select(t,a,b)
```

I added the `as.integer` function since you have different data types in your dataframes.

Comment: I think this drops the 2013 row

Comment: When I try this, I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Argument 2 must be type integer, not double.` - for some reason for me a.x is dbl too. Can be fixed by making sure both are `as.integer`.

Comment: @davsjob nope it does not
@iod that is odd. Maybe version differences? You can always leave the `as.integer` parts out, or force them both to integer.

Comment: @Wietze314 my bad, think i misclicked in R

Comment: @Wietze314 Thanks, this is nice. Is there a way to make the variable inside mutate (`a` or `b`) a variable that is set outside the statement?

Comment: @N08 sorry I don't understand what you mean exactly. If you want the calculated a or b names differently, you can adjust it in the code.

Comment: @Wietze314 My question is, can I make the `a` in the following code a variable that I set outside the dplyr-statement? That would enable me to make this into a function to which I can simply pass the column name and dataframe: `prim %>% full_join(secnd, by = 't') %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(as.integer(a.y),a.x)) %>%
  select(t,a,b)`

Comment: I see what you want, but it is not that easy in dplyr. Check out help function for `mutate_()` (instead of `mutate()`)

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R with a chain `merge` and `ifelse` calls, followed by final column cleanup:

```
final_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="t", all=TRUE), list(prim, secnd, third))

final_df <- within(final_df, {
                      a.x <- ifelse(is.na(a.y), a.x, a.y)
                      b.x <- ifelse(is.na(b.y), b.x, b.y)      
                   })

final_df <- setNames(final_df[,1:3], c("t", "a", "b"))
final_df
#      t a  b
# 1 2007 1  7
# 2 2008 2  8
# 3 2009 3  9
# 4 2010 4 10
# 5 2011 5 11
# 6 2012 5 11
# 7 2013 7 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty. But seems to do the job

```
prim %>% 
  anti_join(secnd, by = "t") %>% 
  full_join(secnd, by = c("t", "a")) %>% 
  select(-b) %>% 
  left_join(prim %>% 
      anti_join(third, by = "t") %>% 
      full_join(third, by = c("t", "b")) %>% 
      select(-a))
```

gives

```
     t a  b
1 2007 1  7
2 2008 2  8
3 2009 3  9
4 2010 4 10
5 2011 5 11
6 2012 5 11
7 2013 7 13
```