# Using variable name in mutate and coalesce

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following piece of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121017/8470971) that merges two dataframes:

```
prim <- data.frame("t"=2007:2012,
                   "a"=1:6,
                   "b"=7:12)

secnd <- data.frame("t"=2012:2013,
                    "a"=c(5, 7))

final_df <- prim %>% full_join(secnd, by = 't') %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(as.integer(a.y),a.x)) %>%
  select(t,a,b)
```

Is it possible to use a variable name instead of hard-coding `a` as done above? I.e., is it possible to make the following non-functioning code work?

```
var <- "a"
final_df <- prim %>% full_join(secnd, by = 't') %>%
  mutate(var = coalesce(as.integer(var.y),var.x)) %>%
  select(t,var,b)
```

Comment: What's the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to convert to symbol with `syms` and evaluate (`!!!`)

```
library(tidyverse)
var <- "a"
prim %>% 
  full_join(secnd, by = "t") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with(var)), as.integer) %>% 
  transmute(t, !! var := coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(paste0(var, c(".y", ".x")))), b)
#     t a  b
#1 2007 1  7
#2 2008 2  8
#3 2009 3  9
#4 2010 4 10
#5 2011 5 11
#6 2012 5 12
#7 2013 7 NA
```

Comment: Thanks. The output is not quite the same though as when I run the code in my own example in the OP?

Comment: @N08  I got it why you got a different result.  The columns are reversed

Comment: Thanks - which columns do you mean?

Comment: @N08  I meant instead of `.x, .y`, you had it `.y`, .`x`

Comment: It is supposed so be `y` first, then `x` (so the OP is correct). But if I make the change in your solution, then I get something different than in the OP

Comment: Also, one more thing is that one of the column is of type different from the other, so have to change it before doing the `coalecse`

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. Would it be possible to update your answer so the output is the same as in my OP? Thanks, I would really appreciate it

Comment: The issue with the earlier part was that I used a.x, a.y in that order.  So, whenever there is a case where the rows have two non-NA, the first value is selected.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a vector of variables to `transmute` in the last line? E.g., pass a vector `vars <- c("t", "b")` instead of writing it manually

Comment: @N08  Yes you can do it.  But convert to symbol with `syms` and do `!!!`

Comment: i.e. `%>% transmute(!!! rlang::syms(vars), !! var := coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(paste0(var, c(".y", ".x")))))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `:=` assignment operator to allow standard-evaluation on the left hand side:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

var <- "a"
final_df <- prim %>% full_join(secnd, by = 't') %>%
  mutate(!!var := coalesce(as.integer(!!sym(paste0(var, ".y"))),!!sym(paste0(var, ".x")))) %>%
  select(t,var,b)
```

Comment: I get the error `Error in sym(paste0(var, ".y")) : could not find function "sym"` when I run the code